# How to re-wrap tiles when re-sizing a tilepane?

Tags: javafx, resize, panel

I am working on a project that includes a JavaFX Tilepane in which a number of buttons are added dynamically.

When the buttons are first added to the tilepane, they form a matrix of 5 columns and 4 rows.  I am trying to figure out how to adjust the number of columns displayed as the width of tilepane is adjusted, in effect "re-wrapping" the tiles that were added previously as the tilepane is resized.

I have searched and experimented with a number of solutions, but I haven't cracked this case yet.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the behavior you describe. For me this just works "out of the box".

Comment: I will do that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi James_D - I went ahead and created a simple mockup of what I described above and you were right - it does work "out of the box". What I forgot to mention about my project is that I embedded the tilePane inside a scroll pane so that I can scroll the tilePane. The scroll pane is, in turn, inserted into an anchor pane (I know, it's confusing). Under these circumstances, the tilePane's contents do not wrap when you expand the tilePane.  Sorry for leaving out what turned out to be very important information.  Perhaps I have to adjust something with the scroll pane.  Any suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: Not entirely clear what behavior you are looking for if the `TilePane` is in a `ScrollPane`, but perhaps calling `setFitToWidth(true)` on the `ScrollPane` will do what you want?

Comment: Yes - that was it.  Thank you a million times for pointing this out. I  greatly appreciate it.